# Use typescript to limit payload type with action name

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using React's useReducer and I am trying to using typescript to achieve when the action type is 'SET', action payload has to be an array, while action type is 'ADD', payload has to be an object.

something like this:

```js
type TItemsAction = TActionItemsSet & TActionItemsAdd;

type TActionItemsSet = {
  type: 'SET';
  payload: TItem[];  // update the whole item array with new array
};

type TActionItemsAdd = {
  type: 'ADD';
  payload: TItem;  // add one new item object to item array
};

function itemsReducer(state: TItem[], action: TItemsAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET': {
      return action.payload;
    }
    case 'ADD': {
      return [...state, action.payload];
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unsupported action type: ${action.type}`);
    }
  }
}

const [items, dispatch] = useReducer(itemsReducer, []);
```

I got typescript complaining:
*The intersection 'TItemsAction' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.*

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Wouldn't you rather use `type TItemsAction = TActionItemsSet | TActionItemsAdd;`? That might probably solve the error Typescript is complaining about.

Comment: Yup, you need a union, not an intersection.

Comment: right, what a noob question now that i see it. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's rather one or the other, not both at a time

```
type TItemsAction = TActionItemsSet | TActionItemsAdd;
```